# How to test with: RSpec + Carrierwave + Carrierwave_backgrounder + Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave, `carrierwave_backgrounder`, Sidekiq and RSpec.

Without the background jobs I tested the processing of my Carrierwave uploader by doing:

```
before do
  ImageUploader.enable_processing = true
  File.open('spec/assets/image.jpg') do |f|
    uploader.store!(f)
  end
end

after do
  ImageUploader.enable_processing = false
  uploader.remove!
end

context 'the thumb version' do
  it 'should scale down a landscape image to be exactly 350 by 350 pixels' do
      uploader.thumb.should have_dimensions(350, 350)
    end
  end
end

context 'the view version' do
  it 'should scale down a landscape image to fit within 1680 by 10000 pixels' do
    uploader.large.should be_no_larger_than(1680, 10000)
  end
end
```

These test does mostly repeat the Uploader implementation but could contain actual logic which needs testing.

I cannot get the uploader to process in the test.
On the [`carrierwave_backgrounder`](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) page they say testing with RSpec has some issues due to `after_commit` hooks not getting called. I tried to use the `TestAfterCommit`-gem with no luck.

Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < BaseImageUploader
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  before :cache, :save_original_filename

  storage :file

  # Resizes to width 1680px (if the image is larger)
  version :large do
    process resize_to_fit: [1680, 10000]
    process :watermark

    def store_dir
      %(uploads/#{model.parent.class.name.pluralize.downcase}/#{model.parent.id}/large)
    end
  end

  # Creates a thumbnail version
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [350, 350]

    def store_dir
      %(uploads/#{model.parent.class.name.pluralize.downcase}/#{model.parent.id}/thumb)
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base   
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
  process_in_background :file

  def original
    file.url
  end

  def thumb
    file.thumb.url
  end

  def view
    file.large.url
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved including on my `rails_helper.rb` file:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

Comment: Cool! Gonna try it out!